# type mapping between cbor (javascript) and c++

Tags: javascript, c++, cbor

I don't know to which C++ types to map the following cbor (javascript) types:

- `null`
- `undefined`

The other way around, I have not idea to which cbor (javascript) type to map the C++ `void` type.

Comment: JSON doesn't have an `undefined` type. And `void` isn't really a data type.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you for the correction, I'll fix the question. I'm writing a rpc implementation using cbor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `undefined` should be mapped to `void`, because:

```
function a() {}
console.log(a())
```

results in:

```
undefined
```

This leaves `::std::nullptr_t` for the `null` type.

Comment: In Javascript, `undefined` is a specific value that you can assign or test for. How do you assign `void`? How do you test if a variable contains `void`?

Comment: You cannot assign `void`, but you can return `void` in a function, you can test, if a function returns `void` with `::std::is_void<decltype(f())>{}`, for example. You can also cast expressions to `void`.

Comment: But does that test whether a value already returned by a function is void? Or does it test what the function declaration is? What I'm saying is the usage doesn't really correspond to undefined values in Javascript.

Comment: It tests the function declaration, as C++ is a statically typed language. The idea is, that I do `cbor_encode(f(cbor_decode<A>(d)...);`, the `cbor_encode()` function will be selected according to what type `f` returns.

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon in C++ to define empty structs for this purpose, e.g. `struct null_type{}` and `struct undefined_type{}`.